# Interactive reporting dashboards

Tags: automation, reporting, dashboard

I work in a corporate environment with many reporting streams. Most of these are in the form of Word documents with different sections. The reports are done on a weekly basis by different groups and subsequently past up to senior levels. Each level re-summarizes the information and generates a new report which generally includes information from reports lower down. All of this is mostly done in word documents which are human-readable.

My question is: Is there a more streamlined method where all members can input summaries specific to their work into a platform and successively more senior levels can have access to this information in the form of an interactive dashboard with the option to filter by different information types. In some cases the information inputs will be numeric or categorical and in others it may be a text blurb with a brief analysis, for example.

Research: I looked into Tableau and Power BI as possible solutions. But I'm uncertain if these would actually replace the Word reports, if the Word reports would be embedded into the dashboard, or something else. Something I've considered is that some information is more suitable to Dashboards (e.g. metrics and visuals) whereas other information is to be read - like a report. Still, it would be nice to be able to house everything under one platform.